# How do I add a column to a df that was created with pd.cut

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

How do I add a column to a df that was created with pd.cut?

```
s = pd.Series(np.arange(10))
df = pd.cut(s, [-5, 0, 5, 10] )
df["Frequency"] =  pd.Series(np.arange(10))
df
```

The output is attached however I would want C to be added to the existing df to the right as a column not at the bottom?

| index | interval | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | (2 -3] | Three |

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call `df` is actually a Series, you can convert using [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = pd.cut(s, [-5, 0, 5, 10] ).to_frame(name='bin')
df["Frequency"] = np.arange(10)
```

Or directly use the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bin': pd.cut(s, [-5, 0, 5, 10]),
                   'Frequency': np.arange(10)
                  })
```

Output:

```
       bin  Frequency
0  (-5, 0]          0
1   (0, 5]          1
2   (0, 5]          2
3   (0, 5]          3
4   (0, 5]          4
5   (0, 5]          5
6  (5, 10]          6
7  (5, 10]          7
8  (5, 10]          8
9  (5, 10]          9
```

Comment: if I wanted to do a groupby on the bin, while summing on the Frequencies, how would I do that ?

Comment: `df.groupby('bin', as_index=False).sum()`, but you should probable read pandas documentation, this is very well explained there.